# Applying a css class on a new div with a different number

Tags: html, css, sass

here is my problem,
I'm summarizing some experiences that I have on my website as you can see here http://www.stefanspeter.fr/eng/aboutEng.html

I want to automate it, I'm using a grid form and each of the section is named as job-[n] (so here it's 1 2 3 for now)

What i want is that each time I add a new one (so 4 5...), it applies the code directly on it

I'm using scss for that, I also have a grid template areas

Here is the grid areas 
I know Ive to change job1.2.3 by probably just job, i just don't know how

```css
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 30px;
  grid-template-areas:
    "bioimage bio bio"
    "job1 job2 job3";
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
```

#### Here is my job css, as u can see on my website, there is a hover effect that i want to apply each time

```css
 div[class*='job-']{
      grid-area: job3;
      &:hover {
        transform: scale(1.2);
        font-size: 20px;
      }
    }
```

I expect my grid area to take probably just job for the row, and each time that i add a new job-* it gets the hover effect,
thank you

Comment: define it from the parent. for example add a class in your row div like `row` and modify your style like `.row > div[class*='job-'] {}`

Comment: So should i add this to the class for example :
`<div class="job job-1">
          <h3>Internship in Auchan, Croix</h3>` to `<div class="job job-1 row">
          <h3>Internship in Auchan, Croix</h3>` ? Sorry I'm not sure I understood what you meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use @each sass function  https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/control/each

and pre-generated 20 entries (for future).

Check this example, i think that's very descriptive:

https://benfrain.com/working-with-lists-and-each-loops-in-sass-with-the-index-and-nth-function/

Comment: thank you, I haven't got to try it yet but I'm sure that was the function i was looking for!